# add/remove datepicker dynamically

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

am just a beginner of php.
    When i click a button i need  to add more date-picker dynamically.I put the code  but when i click the button am getting new textbox not date-picker.plz check my code and tell me where is the  mistake and what i have to do.Here is my code,

```html
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/datepicker.css">
<style type="text/css">
 div{
  padding:8px;
 }
</style>
</head>
<body>
 <script src="js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

    var counter = 2;
 
    $("#addButton").click(function () {
 
 if(counter>10){
            alert("Only 10 textboxes allow");
            return false;
 }   
 
 var newdatepicker = $(document.createElement('div'))
      .attr("id", 'datepicker' + counter);
 
 newdatepicker.after().html('<label> #'+ counter + ' : </label>' +
       '<input class= name="date' + counter + 
       '" id="dateid' + counter + '" value="" >');
 
 newdatepicker.appendTo("#date");
 
 
 counter++;
     });
 
     $("#removeButton").click(function () {
 if(counter==1){
          alert("No more textbox to remove");
          return false;
       }   
 
 counter--;
 
        $("#datepicker" + counter).remove();
 
     });
 
     $("#getButtonValue").click(function () {
 
 var msg = '';
 for(i=1; i<counter; i++){
      msg += "\n date #" + i + " : " + $('#date' + i).val();
 }
       alert(msg);
     });
    });
 </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
  // When the document is ready
        $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.input-daterange').datepicker({
        todayBtn: "linked"
        });
        });
    </script>
 <div id='date'>
  <div class="hero-unit">
   <div class="input-daterange" id="datepicker1" >
      <span class="add-on" style="vertical-align: top;height:20px">Select Leave Date:</span> 
   <input type="text" class="input-small" name="date" id="dateid"/>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <input type='button' value='Add Button' id='addButton'>
 <input type='button' value='Remove Button' id='removeButton'>
 <input type='button' value='Get TextBox Value' id='getButtonValue'>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code is very difficult to read. Work on that! All JavaScript code should be in your header. That makes it much more structured than having several <script> tags spread all over your code.

Comment: ok ok..i will do it. :) @treegarden

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the page loads, you initialize the date picker plugin on the elements found at that time:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.input-daterange').datepicker({
        todayBtn: "linked"
    });
});
```

But then you never initialize it on new elements added later.  So when you add a new element:

```
newdatepicker.appendTo("#date");
```

It's just the uninitialized element that was created.  The plugin was never told about it.  You need to run the plugin on it.

Since the code creates the `id` value, you can simply use that to target the element right after it's been added.  Maybe something like this:

```
newdatepicker.appendTo("#date");
$('#dateid' + counter).datepicker({
    todayBtn: "linked"
});
```

Comment: Sorry :( i cant understand.. @David

Comment: @kanmanik: What part isn't clear?  Using the date picker plugin (most jQuery plugins, for that matter) involves initializing the plugin on a set of matched elements.  Which you're successfully doing.  So in order to use the date picker plugin on new elements, you have to... initialize the plugin on that new set of matched elements.